# C99 complex double - int or float imaginary zero affecting the real value

Tags: c99

Can someone explain why the following code produces different output for the test4 variable compared to the other 3?  I have checked this with gcc version 4.2.1 and 4.5.3 (and others in between).

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but it looks pretty straightforward...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

main()
{
    double complex test1, test2, test3, test4;

    test1 = 81141117.0;
    test2 = 81141117.0 + I * 0;
    test3 = 81141117 + I * 0.0;
    test4 = 81141117 + I * 0;
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I, ", (long)creal(test1), (long)cimag(test1), (long)creal(test2), (long)cimag(test2));
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I\n", (long)creal(test3), (long)cimag(test3), (long)creal(test4), (long)cimag(test4));
}
```

Output:

```
81141117 + 0 I, 81141117 + 0 I
81141117 + 0 I, 81141120 + 0 I
```

It appears that test4, having integer terms only, is being promoted to a float instead of the declared double, and round-off is coming into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (home-built GCC), and also the system provided `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/clang`, and they all produce the same result you report.

I agree with your analysis that there must be a conversion to `float` instead of `double` when both terms of the complex number are expressed as integers.  The C 2011 standard includes the example:

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.9 Initialization

> ¶24 EXAMPLE 1 Provided that `<complex.h>` has been `#include`d, the declarations
>
> ```
> int i = 3.5;
> double complex c = 5 + 3 * I;
> ```
>
> define and initialize i with the value 3 and c with the value 5. 0 + i3. 0.

This clearly indicates that you should be able to write integer expressions and obtain a valid `double complex` (though examples are non-normative).  However, it does not address whether the integer value should be converted to `float` before being converted to `double`, but there's nowhere else in the language that would do that automatically (obviously, you can force it), so it is unlikely to be the intended interpretation.

On the whole, I think this is likely to be a bug that could be reported to the GCC team (and that's not something I advocate doing lightly).  If you run `gcc --help`, the output ends with the message:

```
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html>
```

I would extend your example as shown below (or, rather, I did extend your example as shown below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    double complex test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8;

    test1 = 81141117.0;
    test2 = 81141117.0 + I * 0;
    test3 = 81141117 + I * 0.0;
    test4 = 81141117 + I * 0;
    test5 = (float)81141117 + I * 0;
    test6 = 81141117 + I * (float)0;
    test7 = 81141117.F + I * 0;
    test8 = 81141117 + I * 0.F;
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I\n", (long)creal(test1), (long)cimag(test1), (long)creal(test2), (long)cimag(test2));
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I\n", (long)creal(test3), (long)cimag(test3), (long)creal(test4), (long)cimag(test4));
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I\n", (long)creal(test5), (long)cimag(test5), (long)creal(test6), (long)cimag(test6));
    printf("%ld + %ld I, %ld + %ld I\n", (long)creal(test7), (long)cimag(test7), (long)creal(test8), (long)cimag(test8));
}
```

The output I got was:

```
81141117 + 0 I, 81141117 + 0 I
81141117 + 0 I, 81141120 + 0 I
81141120 + 0 I, 81141120 + 0 I
81141120 + 0 I, 81141120 + 0 I
```

As you can see, the last two lines, where there was an explicit `(float)` cast or explicit float constants, produce the same results as your problematic line (but the values are legitimate).

You might (or might not) want to experiment with the `CMPLX`, `CMPLXF` (and maybe `CMPLXL`) macros; I'd only add them to the reported example if they produced 'interesting' values for some definition of 'interesting'.

---

Compiler version numbers:

```
$ /usr/gcc/v4.7.1/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
$
```